# How to create a function that accepts either a promise or a value and returns the same type as the input argument?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function in TypeScript that can accept either a `A` or a `Promise<A>`, where `A` is some concrete type, and will return the same type (so if it was passed a `Promise<A>`, then `Promise<A>` will be the return type, and vice versa).

I can create a conditional return type based on the input type `func<T = A | Promise<A>, R = T extends A ? A : Promise<A>>(arg: T): R`, but then when I use a type guard that asserts that `arg is Promise<A>` in one branch the type is `T & Promise<A>` but in the other it is still `T`, whereas I would have expect it to be `A` and `Promise<A>`.

On the other hand if I create a function like `func(arg: A | Promise<A>): void` then the type guard works correctly and in the first branch it is `A` and in the other it is `Promise<A>`, but I can't see how to type the return type this way.

```js
interface A {
  x(): void;
}

interface Promise<T> {
}

function isPromise<T>(obj: unknown): obj is Promise<T> {
  return typeof (obj as Promise<T>).then === "function";
}

const a: A = {
  x: () => {}
};
const promiseA = Promise.resolve(a);

function doSomething<T = A | Promise<A>, R = T extends Promise<A> ? Promise<A> : A>(arg: T): R {
  if (isPromise<A>(arg)) {
    // This works, actual type is T & Promise<A> though...
    const type: Promise<A> = arg; 
    return Promise.resolve(a) as R;
  } else {
    // This does not work, actual type is T
    const type: A = arg;
    return a;
  }
}

// This does work, but how to type the return value
function doSomething2(arg: A | Promise<A>): void {
  if (isPromise<A>(arg)) {
    // This works and actual type is Promise<A>
    const type: Promise<A> = arg; 
  } else {
    // This does work!
    const type: A = arg;
  }
}

// This should typecheck
const anA: A = doSomething(a);
// So should this
const aPromiseA: Promise<A> = doSomething(promiseA);
// This should fail but doesn't - return type should be A
const aPromiseB: Promise<A> = doSomething(a);
// This should fail but doesn't - return type should be Promise<A>
const anB: A = doSomething(promiseA);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4CgC+WuiSyIoAKUA9gLbADOEAPACoB8mu+MAriAmMBRDI65anUasAFBQBGAKwBcyHgGsQFAO4gAlEtlzhtZKJr1mbbMmRQIYLlCFgAngAcIFGMmnzkcIyfFzbQA6MAALCCEAXhjkACJuXn5BOIBuDiwEQVowXyV0KMwcdKyQHOQXSlMIAuMq8WCbWgoAGwA3CEk4bXSsRL4BIQATCgBlalsw0ABzZmRC9AAfOrEzVBYAGmQAJXnkJmQIAA9IECH-erW2AH4V6oZ15HyWLqhppSZdHfYrYE9JESXRjrV7TbTaH5WZAAemh+ymRg0FCgKloW0QdjgLWQzjchn2yAAZHdAo9whQuNMwsEaVgochSuVcRAlAErns4G9Usg6VCbHYHCT6I0IM12p1ur4jNt0lYcIcWvRIVZYfC6MgRqLkOpckiUei+FwsTjXCh1UxeVZGblmfkOVzLdZbPYhHBZcg8HgsKqmAiNRQtXqVFsZFxcmFNDiKCa8eEUPyXcg2liuBA+jwBoJ-eMqJMZgAmUF25Zs4EsL5tCjAIaQv5eQGrMug8HKmFw33qoNGOBnXyG43M-Glh4sR3WmMsoVl+3Tbm8+UQRUoSxQn1+zWI5EqACEY+yNtNdsKnNn84ya-VtAjXBaNeZCAiCBUmX3vhAqCP2Ym4RmXR63rhcZkCvClbxxBEXzKXI4FLD8pxHPYRhzPMQGmSRKkbVB-wvIwQJvGt4GAbEAFonQFRxTWA68wJkFBUEg8oYKBAAhVkgQQwokO-KZUL-dIcKo0CCLgIjkFIhNBUHPCaLIdj1gY6CQFYtBELGbjfww6osNSIA)

Comment: The generic usage seems unnecessary, just do it with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads): https://tsplay.dev/m0vjxw

Comment: I've added the code into the question

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe the overloads worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. Yes, you could work with [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but you would have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) return types.

Sometimes the usage of [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) can simplify things a lot because the correct types are used automatically depending on the overload you call.

```
interface A {}
interface Promise<T> {}

function isPromise<T>(obj: unknown): obj is Promise<T> {
  return typeof (obj as Promise<T>).then === "function";
}

const a: A = {};

function doSomething(arg: Promise<A>): Promise<A>;
function doSomething(arg: A): A;
function doSomething(arg: A | Promise<A>) {
  if (isPromise<A>(arg)) {
    // implementation ...
    return arg;
  } else {
    // implementation ...
    return arg;
  }
}

const aA: A = doSomething(a);
//    ^? const aA: A
const aPromiseA = doSomething(Promise.resolve(a));
//    ^? const aPromiseA: Promise<A>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4F8CwAoUSWRFABSgHsBbYAZwgB4AVAPk1z3xgFcQExgFEMjrlqdRqwAUFAEYArAFzJeAaxAUA7iACUyufJG1kYmvWZsM+ZMigQw3KMLABPAA4QKMZDIXI4xqYSFjoAdGAAFhDCALxxyABEPHwCQgkA3Pgc+AhCtGD+yugx7JmceMn8gsIAJhQAytT2EaAA5lJwUK3KQeaoLHomlGaM-WWVqbUNTZFtHV1Fg6jjvFVCyHWNVM1znd1oyAA+Q+J9A5jWIt5SosPB-fOtOjoXeDY2APQfIlRuADYQbbgOCTZChcGXGx2BxOfxdMo2LDICB-eivd7IL4-f6A6JgEHVMEQt7vaGOYR7BHIDjZPC5ED5fzFDbTbazEDtOA6MpY94APQA-Dk8gU4L0IMzNjMWhypOLQnZaBQ-gA3CAdZ48778gVAA)

Comment: A minor nitpick with the type check - it's possible for something to not be a `Promise` but to still have a `then` method. Objects like these, sometimes called "thenables", can behave just like a `Promise` in a lot of important ways, such as working with the `await` keyword, but they do differ in some ways too. So you could run into trouble with that type check in some edge cases, depending on what else your code uses. If you want to be certain that an object is a `Promise`, you can use `obj instanceof Promise` in your typeguard instead to check that directly.